# There are 10 nuts. 4 of them are defective. If you draw 4 nuts, what is the probability that you draw first two defective and then 2 correct?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> There are 10 nuts. 4 of them are defective. If you draw 4 nuts, what is the probability that you draw first two defective and then 2 correct?

My solution:

$$\frac{\binom{4}{2} \binom{6}{2}}{\binom{10}{4}}= 0.429$$

But the book say its wrong answer and the correct answer is $0.071$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be $\frac{4}{10}\cdot\frac{3}{9}\cdot\frac{6}{8}\cdot\frac{5}{7}$:

For the first pick, there are 4 defective nuts out of 10. For the second pick, there are 3 defective nuts in the remaining 9 nuts. For the third pick, there are 6 good nuts in the remaining 8. For the last pick, there are 5 good nuts in the remaining 7.

Building on your answer: you calculated the probability to pick 2 defective and 2 good nuts, without taking the order into account. Two defective and two good nuts can be chosen in 6 possible orders (here $6=\binom{4}{2}$), so to get the correct answer we have to divide your answer by $6=\binom{4}{2}$.

So the answer is $\frac{4}{10}\cdot\frac{3}{9}\cdot\frac{6}{8}\cdot\frac{5}{7}=\frac{\binom{4}{2}\binom{6}{2}/\binom{10}{4}}{\binom{4}{2}}=\frac{\binom{6}{2}}{\binom{10}{4}}$.

Comment: can you write the solution as my answer (use  combinatorics and Factorial)

Comment: thank you for a very good answer :)